# Does the transform function in plyr change variable names?

Tags: r, plyr

The data set I am working with has two and three-word variable names with space in between.

```
> names(final.data1)
##  [1] "Vehicle ID"           "Frame ID"             "Total Frames"        
##  [4] "Global Time"          "Local X"              "Local Y"             
##  [7] "Global X"             "Global Y"             "Vehicle Length"      
## [10] "Vehicle width"        "Vehicle class"        "Vehicle velocity"    
## [13] "Vehicle acceleration" "Lane"                 "Preceding Vehicle ID"
## [16] "Following Vehicle ID" "Spacing"              "Headway"             
## [19] "svel"                 "sacc"                 "PrecVehClass"
```

I didn't change the names and kept doing analyses as is. When I used `transform` of  `plyr` package, I got 2 columns for some of the variables which contained same numbers but had different names.

```
# Determining when the lane change occured
final.data1 <- ddply(final.data1, c("`Vehicle class`", "`Vehicle ID`"), transform, 
    lane.change = c(NA, ifelse(diff(Lane) != 0, "yes", ".")))
ordr <- with(final.data1, order(`Vehicle ID`))
final.data1 <- final.data1[ordr, ]  #sort in ascending order by vehicle ID
names(final.data1)
##  [1] "Vehicle class"        "Vehicle ID"           "Vehicle.ID"          
##  [4] "Frame.ID"             "Total.Frames"         "Global.Time"         
##  [7] "Local.X"              "Local.Y"              "Global.X"            
## [10] "Global.Y"             "Vehicle.Length"       "Vehicle.width"       
## [13] "Vehicle.class"        "Vehicle.velocity"     "Vehicle.acceleration"
## [16] "Lane"                 "Preceding.Vehicle.ID" "Following.Vehicle.ID"
## [19] "Spacing"              "Headway"              "svel"                
## [22] "sacc"                 "PrecVehClass"         "lane.change"
```

See `Vehicle ID` and `Vehicle.ID`? Why is this happening and how can I prevent this if I don't want to change original variable names?

Comment: I suspect that this has something to do with the `"."` inside the `ifelse`. However, I haven't fully understood, what you are doing with `c(NA, ifelse(..))`. Wouldn't it make more sense to write `lane.change = ifelse(diff(Lane) != 0, "yes", NA)`?

Comment: It does make more sense but `NA`s in my data give different meaning in different analyses and I don't want to confuse myself. I can use `no` I guess but why would input variable's name change if I specify the `.` to a new variable `lane.change`?

Comment: Why are you using `c(NA, ifelse(..))` then? (I mean why not only the `ifelse` part of it)

Comment: And as far as I know `plyr`, if you want to group by two variables, you would write, for example, `ddply(final.data1, .(Var1, Var2), ...)`. Compare that to your code.

Comment: Could you include some sample data to make your problem reproducible? That would make it easier to find out why the name changes happen.

Comment: I really think that simply changing the column names so that they don't have spaces will be _far_ less work.

Comment: @beginneR I am using `c(NA, ifelse(..))` because after taking `diff`erence the total number of rows decrease by 1 for every `Vehicle ID` so I put `NA` in the first row. As for your second comment, I will try with `.(Var1, Var2)`  format and update with the results. Creating representative sample data is difficult in this case but I'll try. Thanks for your suggestions. @joran You are right but unfortunately the later analyses contain some of the original column names.

Comment: ok, got it now. It seems that @aosmith has the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Yes, I got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually with `transform`, which is "checking" the variable names.  If you add `check.names = FALSE` after `transform` within the `ddply` call I think you'll get what you want.  Here's an example with a toy dataset.

```
dat = data.frame("Vehicle class" = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 4), 
                 "Vehicle ID" = rep(c("c","d"), times = 4), 
                 Lane = sample(0:3, 8, replace = TRUE), 
                 "Vehicle Length" = runif(8, 0, 100), check.names = FALSE)

require(plyr)

# Using transform changes names in output data.frame
ddply(dat, .(`Vehicle class`, `Vehicle ID`), transform, 
    lane.change = c(NA, ifelse(diff(Lane) != 0, "yes", ".")))

# Adding check.names = FALSE to change this behavior
ddply(dat, .(`Vehicle class`, `Vehicle ID`), transform, check.names = FALSE,
    lane.change = c(NA, ifelse(diff(Lane) != 0, "yes", ".")))
```